# System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Server was unable to process request. ---> ... with key 0 was not found

Tags: web-services, outsystems

I have a simple service (C# web service) that accepts an integer and returns an integer, i have tested it using Storm it is working properly.

Now i am calling this service in a for loop in a file with around 2000 records approx, this service is failing giving the above error with some records. If i run the error file it goes through as if nothing was wrong, what might be the problem please help.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by "If i run the error file"?

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't seem related to it being a web service call: it seems to indicate you either tried to **Get*Entity*** and passed in a zero/NullIdentifier() (not a valid Id), or maybe you tried an **Create*Entity*** and that entity has a foreign key that is not filled in (i.e. zero/NullIdentifier() again).

I would start by checking the logic inside the WS method for those action calls and the inputs you are using there.